# ActionItem appears after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have faced quite weird problem I've been fighting with for several days. I have two fragments `A` and `B`.

While `A` is visible I have `ActionItem` visible. Up on replacing fragment `A` with `B` I hide `ActionItem` which are filters for data in `onCreate()` (tried in `onConfigurationChanged()` too). And it DOES hide. But when the orientation changes to landscape this `ActionItem` is restored in action bar.

**What could be the reason?**

Also interesting fact that `ActionItem` is being restored in **standard** java class called `Looper`. It "loops" there for several times and then restores `ActionItem`.

---

Now the code. Thats how I create it in activity that stands for fragments navigation:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.global_filters, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(this.menu);
}
```

global_filters.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".NavigationActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_filters"
    android:title="Filters"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_white"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

items for filters are added in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   int id = item.getItemId();

   switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_filters:
            menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_filters); // SAME ID AS MENU ID
            popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
            //if logined - show user. Else guest
            if (state) {
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_filters_user);
            } else {
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_filters_guest);
            }
//....
}
```

popup_filters_user.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_purchased_user"
    android:title="Purchased"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_price_user"
    android:title="Price"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_author_user"
    android:title="Author"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_difficulty_user"
    android:title="Difficulty"/>
</menu>
```

and finally how I hide `ActionItem` in Fragment's `B` `onCreate()`:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //....other logic

    //hide action Item
    View menuItemView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_filters);
    if (menuItemView != null) {
        menuItemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried, use option menu in each fragment separately.

Comment: @Ishrat I would appreciate if you write code sample of your possible solution. Or at least describe it more precisely

Comment: Please have look to my answer below what i was trying to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved this by myself. The problem was that I didn't save the state of `actionBar` after I modified its elements.

All I was needed to is to write `setRetainInstance(true);` after every items modification.

As always solution is simple...

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that when the orientation changes the whole activity is re-drawn (ie. successive callbacks of the lifecycle methods).

Also, the [fragments' lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) is closely tied to it's host (the activity).

From what I can see you seem to be hiding the fragment `A` from within the fragment's `B` `onCreate()` method. Try adding `Log.d (Tag, String)` methods in the lifecycle methods of the fragment to see when these are called.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your fragment onCreate method set

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Then create option menu for each fragment separately by overriding

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Now you don't need to handle menu items in your activity.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I belive that would simplify `ActionBar` management, thanks. Will use it in my project. Although the problem was in other thing.